# Android Progress DialogBox is not displaying?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-location

I am trying to show a `ProgressDialog` for five seconds on user interface to block the UI so that my locationClient can get connected and after five seconds.

I am dismissing the dialog box.But the dialog box is not displaying at all and mobile screen goes black for 3-4 seconds.Is it happening because I am running this code On `UiThread`?. If yes is their any other approach i can follow to stop for 5 seconds and then execute the pending code.

My code for the thread is following:

```
public void startConnecting(final boolean isSearchWarnings) {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait","Long operation starts...", true);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
                            break;

                        } else {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (isSearchWarnings) {
                    new getWarnings().execute(false);
                } else {
                    new getWarnings().execute(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this

```
   MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
```

And then

```
   Thread.sleep(1000);
```

You are calling sleep on the ui thread. This blocks the ui thread which you should not do. You will get ANR.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

If you want to cause a delay use `handler`

[give a delay of few seconds without using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704020/give-a-delay-of-few-seconds-without-using-threads)

Comment: I am trying to implement it using handler.Will post the code if it work